# DISABLE wordpress upgrade page

Tags: functions, wp-admin, security, upgrade

For security purpose I want to Disable the adresse below:

...../upgrade.php

It's give informations about the version of wordpress used.

Comment: Note that it is entirely easy to figure out the WP version of *any* WP site. For instance this technique: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/check-your-wordpress-version-without-logging-in-to-your-admin-section/ . Or this http://tech-lives.com/find-wordpress-version-of-a-site/ . Or several other techniques found on the googles. My point is that hiding the upgrade.php file via htaccess is not the only thing to think about if you are worried about the security of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this on the web host without actually any PHP code. Using the same procedure as is recommended to deny access to `wp-config.php`, you can also deny access to `upgrade.php`.

All you need to do is create a file named `.htaccess` in `wp-admin` and put the following in it:

```
<files upgrade.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

What this does is it tells the web server software do deny access to `upgrade.php` from everybody. That way if someone tries to access it, the server will return a 403 error instead.

This assumes your web host is running Apache as its web server software. If it is not, their support staff should be able to assist you.